# AngularJs Directive to simplify form inputs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My company has theme requirements and has asked me to do some research on AngularJs.  To that end, I'd like to show how Angular can be used to implement our theme.

[Here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sbyl7ACGXFQO41KGnMDz?p=preview) of what I have so far.

Here is the HTML of what I have that works great.

```
<form name="frmLogin" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-field" data-ng-class="{'error': frmLogin.txtLastName.$invalid && frmLogin.txtLastName.$dirty && !frmLogin.txtLastName.$focused}">
    <label for="txtLastName" class="required">Email</label>
    <input id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" type="text" data-ng-model="user.lastName" required autofocus ng-focus />
    <div class="inline-validation" data-ng-show="frmLogin.txtLastName.$invalid && frmLogin.txtLastName.$dirty && !frmLogin.txtLastName.$focused">
      {{getError(frmLogin.txtLastName.$error,
        {
          required: "LastName is required"
        }
      )}}
    </div>
  </div>      
</form>
```

I'm working on a directive to simplify the HTML for the developer.

Here's my idea.

```
<form name="frmUserName" novalidate>
  <ff-text-input control-name="txtFirstName" control-label="First Name" ng-model="user.userEmail"></ff-text-input>
</form>
```

Being new to this, I'm struggling with the directive.

I don't know how to grab the whole `frmLogin.txtLastName.$invalid && frmLogin.txtLastName.$dirty && !frmLogin.txtLastName.$focused` so the developer doesn't have to.

I'm able to determine the form name and control name by using `ctrl.$name + "." + scope.controlName` but I'm lost on how to apply that to the `$invalid` etc...

Thanks,
Duane

Comment: Just copy paste your html into template and add attribute where you will pass form name, or use jQuery: `var formName = element.closest('form').attr('name');` when you'll have name of the form you should be able to just use `formName[attr.controlName].$invalid`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  Don't I have the form from the ctrl argument in my link function?  I keep thinking I should be able to do `console.log(ctrl[controlName]);` but I keep getting undefined.  I can get the form name by `var formName = ctrl.$name` and the controlName by `var controlName = scope.controlName` but when I put the two together, I get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you want your directive to interact with form states, you need to have a form controller in your directive. 
You can do this with

```
app.directive('inputValidate', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: true,
                require: '^form',
```

The `require` tell Angular that your directive depends on the form, so Angular moves up the DOM, until it finds a `form`, and when it finds a `form`, it passes a controller to the directive and you can receive that controller like this.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, formController){
```

Here `formController` refers to the controller of the form.

Now, for the your last query, suppose you have an input box with type defined as `employeeID`, with some custom rule plus juggling, you are able to conclude that input is wrong. To inform Angular that this input is wrong, you can use `$setValidity` method of the formController.

The syntax is like

```
formController[controlName].$setValidity(str, value);
```

where `controlName` is the name of the control, str is the field for which validation has failed, and value would be either true or false depending upon the your validation state.

Depending upon your validation state and key, Angular will apply fallowing class to the element. For example, if your key in empId and input is invalid, the in class attribute of the element, you can see this.

```
class = "ng-invalid-empId"
```

And if it is valid and you have told angular with formController using this.

```
formController[controlName].$setValidity('empId', true);
```

You would have something like this.

```
class="ng-valid-empId"
```